# Parallel fetching comments from Facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, parallel-processing

I need to fetch a large amount of comments from Facebook post. So, the simplest solution is:

1. Get https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/post_id/comments?access_token=token
2. Get "after" paging cursor.
3. Go to next page.

My question is: can i parallelize my solution? I did not find anything in fb documentation. Are there any tricks?

Comment: paging is what you need. not sure what the exact question is though, you are using paging already (paging link). of course you can also program this, with a recursive function, for example.

Comment: If you use FQL, you can do something like this: `SELECT id
  FROM comment
 WHERE object_id = %id%
 LIMIT 2
OFFSET 0` and `SELECT id
  FROM comment
 WHERE object_id = %id%
 LIMIT 2
OFFSET 2` and run this queries in two separate threads. So, exact question is: can i do something like this without FQL?

Comment: FQL is deprecated since a very long time.

Comment: and again, you can use a recursive function to get all entries.